# onclick event with changing parameters to jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a code that i need to send 1 parameter of id which change every time:

```
echo '<img src="'.$image[0].'" alt="'.get_the_title().'" onclick="ShowPicContent('.get_the_ID().')" id="img_product_id" />';
```

how do I transfer it to jquery .click event and send the id of the img?

Comment: assuming there are 2 or more img tags :)

Comment: why not just pass in the id when its created

Comment: question is unclear, do you want to convert `onclick="..."` in jQuery? Also, where do you want to send the id of the img?

Comment: I read all the products from a category and place images of the product in divs. each product have an id that i want to send into jquery .click event that use AJAX to load the product details in the main div

Answer (score 0):

EDIT

php

```
echo '<img src="'.$image[0].'" alt="'.get_the_title().'" data-id="'.get_the_ID().'" class="clickable" />';
```

jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
    $('.clickable').click( function() {
        var id = $(this).data('id'); // get the "data-id" attribute

        // YOUR AJAX CODE HERE

    });
});
```

Comment: i thought keeping the id of the img constant becouse i have other images that i don't need to do any thing on click, for example the logo image, i thought doing the 'img_product_id' as a trigger $('#img_product_id').click( function(e)...

Comment: IDs should be unique. Just add class="clickable" or somthing similar to use it as a trigger. Still, what ID should you pass to jQuery?

Comment: i will pass the product id

Comment: in that case, I edited my answer: you output the product id inside a data-attribute, then you retrieve it from jQuery. Also, IMGs are triggered using their class .clickable

Comment: thanks to you all, it works but not with data('id'), just attr('id')